# How do I use PHPUnit to test __construct with arguments?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm new to PHPUnit, and unit testing in general. I can't seem to find a clear tutorial or resource on how best to test:

1. Passing no argument fails.
2. How to pass an argument for a constructor test.
3. Passing an empty argument results in the expected exception.

How would I approach testing this constructor?

```
<?php

class SiteManagement {
    public function __construct (array $config) {
        // Make sure we actually passed a config
        if (empty($config)) {
            throw new \Exception('Configuration not valid', 100);
        }

        // Sanity check the site list
        if (empty($config['siteList'])) {
            throw new \Exception('Site list not set', 101);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: new SiteManagement ( $configarray );

Answer (score 3):

The [example 2.11](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit-exceptions-examples-exceptiontest-php) of the PHPUnit documentation shows how to test exceptions.

For your specific class, it would be something like this:

```php
$this->expectException(Exception::class);

$object = new SiteManagement([]);
```

You shouldn't test if the method fails without arguments unless those arguments are optional. This would be out of the scope for a unit test.

Answer (score 1):

A good test battery for your class would be:

```
/** @test */
public function shouldFailWithEmptyConfig(): void
{
    $config = [];

    $this->expectException(\Exception::class);
    $this->expectExceptionMessage('Configuration not valid');
    $this->expectExceptionCode(100);

    new SiteManagement($config);
}

/** @test */
public function shouldFailWithoutSiteListConfig(): void
{
    $config = ['a config'];

    $this->expectException(\Exception::class);
    $this->expectExceptionMessage('Site list not set');
    $this->expectExceptionCode(101);

    new SiteManagement($config);
}

/** @test */
public function shouldMakeAFuncionality(): void
{
    $config = [
        'siteList' => '',
    ];

    $siteManagement = new SiteManagement($config);

    self::assertSame('expected', $siteManagement->functionality());
}
```